# how to specify trusted certificate to kubernetes master?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes

I am creating a k8s cluster on AWS using http://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/aws/ 
After exporting required environment variables and running ./kubernetes/cluster/kube-up.sh I am able to create k8s cluster. 
But I am getting "Certificate Error" in crome on accessing kubernetes-master, can some one help me how to specify trusted certificate which is already available with me to kubernetes-master?
During creation I can see logs as,
Generating certs for alternate-names:

Answer (score 0):

Each cluster is given its own certificate hierarchy, which is not signed by a root CA that is trusted by your web browser. For Chrome to connect without a warning, you will need to add the cluster CA certificate into your root certificate store so that it is trusted by your machine.

See https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/7307#issuecomment-96130676

Comment: Thanks robert-bailey! But adding certificate to root certificate store will solve problem on my machine only. Can we somehow tweak kube-up script to use valid certiticate?

Comment: Right now the [script will unconditionally create certificates](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/cluster/common.sh#L685). We could certainly tweak it such that if you provided all of the necessary certificates it would use those instead of generating new ones. Then you could work with a trusted CA to generate all of the certificate pairs that you need and pass them in as configuration options. If this is something that you'd like to see, please file a [feature request on github](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/new) and/or send a pull request.